# How to style 3 unorderd lists horizontally in 1 div

Tags: html, css

How Can I display 3 unordered lists horizontally next to each other? 
The 3 ul are wrapped in 1 div called 'tax'.

I've tried the following, but it's not showing correctly.
I know I can solve this by wrapping each ul with a div, but I don't want to use extra markup when it's not necessarily.

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Eric87/LKp69/13/

**HTML**

```
<div id="tax">
<hr>
<h2>
Recent News </h2>
<ul id="recent-news">
    <li>
    <a href='#'>
    new release </a>
    &#32;&rsaquo; </li>
    <li>
    <a href='#'>
    testing titel </a>
    &#32;&rsaquo; </li>
</ul>
<h2>
Categories </h2>
<ul id="categories">
    <li>
    <a href="#">
    Audio </a>
    &#32;&rsaquo; </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">
    Uncategorized </a>
    &#32;&rsaquo; </li>
</ul>
<h2>
Archives </h2>
<ul id="archives">
    <li>
    <a href=''>
    August 2013 </a>
    &nbsp; </li>
    <li>
    <a href='#'>
    July 2013 </a>
    &nbsp; </li>
    <li>
    <a href='#'>
    May 2013 </a>
    &nbsp; </li>
    <li>
    <a href='#'>
    December 2012 </a>
    &nbsp; </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
 #tax {
margin-top:100px;
}

#tax ul {
width:33%;
list-style:outside;
}

#categories,#archives,#recent-news {
display:inline-block;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to align **two** elements horizontally, both the `h2` and the `ul` that goes with it, that's why it's not working 'as expected'. The only way to solve this, to make both those elements act as one, is to add an extra markup element around **both** of them, and apply regular horizontal layout rules to that element. I'd recommend a `section` for this, like:

```
<section id="archives">
  <h2>Section title</h2>
  <ul><!-- bunch of list items --></ul>
</section>
```

This isn't "unnecessary extra markup", this is required markup if you want 2 elements to layout as 1.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. So as I understand, it's only possible to do it with a div around each ul. I already knew that, but thanks anyway. I thought maybe it's also possible to do it without a div, but if it's required I will do that.

Answer (score 2):

Create a wrapper for each item and assign each  item a class called "pull-left". And then, add style below:

```
<div class="pull-left">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>  
<div class="pull-left">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<div class="pull-left">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is your css code for pull-left class:

```
.pull-left { float: left; }
```

Answer (score 1):

For horizontal you basically have to use div to wrap ul.

http://jsfiddle.net/5d5eM/

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
}
br { clear: left; }
```

Answer (score 1):

**HERE IS A WORKING LIVE DEMO: [CLick HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMWR/)**

i have a add a extra `<div>` for all `<ul>` and put it to float:left:

basically its all

Answer (score 1):

here create one wrapper div for including with header tag and ul.  For example here I create wrapper div with name of "test".

```
<div id="tax">
    <div class="test">
    <h2>
    Recent News </h2>
    <ul id="recent-news">
        <li>
        <a href='#'>
        new release </a>
        &#32;&rsaquo; </li>
        <li>
        <a href='#'>
        testing titel </a>
        &#32;&rsaquo; </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    <h2>
    Categories </h2>
    <ul id="categories">
        <li>
        <a href="#">
        Audio </a>
        &#32;&rsaquo; </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">
        Uncategorized </a>
        &#32;&rsaquo; </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    <h2>
    Archives </h2>
    <ul id="archives">
        <li>
        <a href=''>
        August 2013 </a>
        &nbsp; </li>
        <li>
        <a href='#'>
        July 2013 </a>
        &nbsp; </li>
        <li>
        <a href='#'>
        May 2013 </a>
        &nbsp; </li>
        <li>
        <a href='#'>
        December 2012 </a>
        &nbsp; </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css :

```
<style type="text/css">
 #tax {
margin-top:100px;
}


#categories,#archives,#recent-news {
display:inline-block;
float:left;
}
.test{width:33%; 
float:left;}

</style>
```

[see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LKp69/15/)